# Why I'm getting required error after selecting the first value in a select in angular 9 app?

Tags: angular

I have the following template which include select component with options:

```html
 

    <select class="selectpicker_std" [(ngModel)]="fund.subscription_frequency" #subscriptionFrequency="ngModel" name="subscription_frequency" [compareWith]="compareSubscriptionFrequenciesByOptionId" required>
    <option [ngValue]="null">{{defaultSelect}}</option>
         <option *ngFor="let sf of frequencies" [value]="sf.frequency">{{sf.name}}</option>
     </select>
     <div *ngIf="subscriptionFrequency.errors && (subscriptionFrequency.touched || fund3FormDirective.submitted)">
         <div class="error_message" *ngIf="subscriptionFrequency?.errors?.required">
             <span class="e_arrow"></span>
             <i>Please select subscription frequency</i>
         </div>
     </div>
```

This is the compare method:

```js
    compareSubscriptionFrequenciesByOptionId(idFirst, idSecond) {       
        return idFirst && idSecond && idFirst.frequency == idSecond.frequency;         
      }
```

What's happened is this: scenario 1: When selecting the first value the required error message appear.
Scenario 2: when selecting any other value, there is no error and the data save with no issue.

Comment: Can you create working sample in stackblitz?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After removing the compare method all works fine:

```
 [compareWith]="compareSubscriptionFrequenciesByOptionId"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, **null** value is considered a **false** value to **required** validator.

To solve this, my seguestion is to replace:

`[ngValue]="null"`

by

`[ngValue]="'null'"`

like that, the validator will consider 'null' as a **string value** (because it's wrapped by '..') , BUT do not forget to check it with a string **comparaison**.

Comment: That's works but to accept the answer can you advise how I get the required message to work?

Comment: @user2304483 in that case, i suggest you to make your custom validator instead of using the angular core required validator. In the custom Validator you can look for values and compare it to take even **null** values and in case where there is an error, you can check it with its **Key** (that you will define when making your custom validator) then get this error by its key (using .hasError(..) method). 
You can look at this ressource for more informations: [Build Angular Custom Validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Comment: I'm not using reactive form for this page, your solution almost work, what's happen now id that I don't get error at all

Comment: @user2304483 it's the same approach bro, check this too about: [using custom validator in template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms)  **The <input> element carries the HTML validation attributes: required and minlength. It also carries a custom validator directive, forbiddenName. For more information, see the Custom validators section** [this section specially](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms)

Comment: Well, that's not quick will have to try it tomorrow, i thougt i get quick solution :-)

Comment: @user2304483 yes, it should take a little time to take a look at the different aspects: Core Validatos,  Custom Validators and Directives (they are the main concepts to solve your problem). good luck !

Comment: I did the validation and what I can see it that the first select is null and that's the problem, so basically the problem persist, any idea why the first valid select also return 'null'?